# vuejs 2 nextTick() return

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to return some data using nextTick() in vuejs 2 as following

```
getProperty() {
   this.$nextTick(function() {
      return 'hello';
   });
}
```

It doesn't work. Any clue?

Answer (score 4):

`this.$nextTick` this function does not return anything; it just executes your callback after refreshing all new data.

so if you want to set some flag or data you can use modal/variable for that.

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    msg: 'hello'
  },
  methods: {
    someTask: function () {
      this.msg = 'hello next tick';
      this.$nextTick(function() {
        this.printVar();
      });
    },
    printVar: function() {
      // here this variable will be changed to latest value
      // or call another function where this value is used
      // this.anotherFunction();
      console.log(this.msg);
    }
  },   
  ready: function () {
    this.someTask();
  }   
});
```

or just let us know what you want to do with that so we can provide you better answer.

Comment: Cool! Tks for answering! I want to insert my method in the view getProperty() and return a value according to the logic! Something like getProperty() { return "Hello view"; }

Comment: nice ! you can use "printVar" in your view directly and it can return value :)
so your "getProperty()" can be same as here just addition to return some value

Comment: @HardikSatasiya, the function *does* return the value. The problem is that `nextTick` is **asynchronous**, which means that by the time it is called `getProperty` already finished its execution and returned nothing, and the newly returned value just vaporizes into thin air, as it can not be assigned.

Comment: Yes, it may be returning the promise in case we don't pass call back in new vue version 2.0+, but if we pass call back i dont see its returning any value.

Comment: source : https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/f5cd29e1d8197613c4dfb4013b240784c3b64e43/flow/component.js#L47
as well its definition https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/471de4a31d229e681cc9dce18632b5bcab944c77/src/core/util/next-tick.js#L90